# How to add property to bean during runtime in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring. I have the below Person bean with name, address and age as properties. Now I would like to add new property called gender to the Person bean in my custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor.  My person bean implements AttributeAccessor.

XML configuration file

```
<bean id="PersonBean" class="com.mkyong.common.Person">             
   <property name="name" value="mkyong"></property>
   <property name="address" value="address ABC"></property>
   <property name="age" value="29"></property>                           
</bean>                                                                 
<bean class="com.mkyong.common.CustomBeanFactory"></bean>
```

Custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
public class CustomBeanFactory implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {
    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = arg0.getBeanDefinition("PersonBean");
    beanDefinition.setAttribute("gender", "Male");
    }                                                                       
}
```

Person class
          `enter code here`

```
public class Person implements AttributeAccessor{

private String name;
private String address;
private int age;

public Person(){
    System.out.println("Creating bean Person "+this);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String[] attributeNames() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getAttribute(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasAttribute(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object removeAttribute(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}   
}
```

Client program

```
public static void main(String [] arg){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"Spring-Autoscan.xml"});

    Person personObj = (Person)context.getBean("PersonBean");
    System.out.println("Value of gender attribute "+personObj.getAttribute("gender"));
}
```

If I access the gender I am getting null

Please let me know how to set and get properties dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your setAttribute() method is empty. It does not store the value.

```
public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Create a `Map` inside where you can store the value and get it back. Like this

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public void setAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) {
    map.put(arg0, arg1);
} 

public Object getAttribute(String arg0) {
    return map.get(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree. But what is the use of beanDefinition.setAttribute method used inside the Custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor class